# PHP table leaderboard

Tags: php, mysqli, html-table

I'm trying to make a leaderboard of my favorite movies.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Rank</td>
        <td>Score</td>
        <td>Year</td>
    </tr>

<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "", "", "movies");
    $sql = ("SELECT score, year FROM mymovies ORDER BY score DESC");
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $rank = 1;

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result)) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo "<td>{$rank}</td>
                  <td>{$row['score']}</td>
                  <td>{$row['number_of_times']}</td>";
            $rank++;
        }
    }
?>
</table>
```

The problem is that it shows the data in one line instead of showing it underneath each other like this:

```
Rank Score Year
1    25    1999
2    23    1987
3    20    2005
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably because you need to include a `<tr>` tag ..

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Rank</td>
        <td>Score</td>
        <td>Year</td>
    </tr>

<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "", "", "movies");
    $sql = ("SELECT score, year FROM mymovies ORDER BY score DESC");
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $rank = 1;

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result)) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo "<tr>
                      <td>{$rank}</td>
                      <td>{$row['score']}</td>
                      <td>{$row['number_of_times']}</td>
                  </tr>";
            $rank++;
        }
    }
?>
</table>
```